# JavaScript Arrays - Remove duplicates and just return just one

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

If I have an array (category) that have multiple of the same values (retail for example)

How do I remove duplicates and just return just one (Retail, Technology, Auto etc)

So it just leaves data like this:

Before:

```
category: “Retail, Retail, Retail, Technology”,
```

After:

```
category: “Retail, Technology”
```

I have a code example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/late-cdn-2stdj

---

Update:

See when I do it with const of categories it works:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sky-zx4mo

but when I try and do it with a .map to access the array it doesn't that is where I am at:

https://codesandbox.io/s/late-cdn-2stdj

Comment: I might have tried searching for this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
const categories = "Retail, Retail, Retail, Technology";

const listCategories = [...new Set(categories.split(/,\s*/))];

Or alternative:
const listCategories = [...new Set(categories.match(/[A-z]+/g))];


const result = listCategories.join(", ");
console.log({result})
```

Comment: @Tired_Man you are most welcome!